# SQL Server & Storage Question - What's the right choice?

Tags: sql-server, storage, sysdba

I am a young DBA from Germany and I am the administrator for our customers SQL Servers.

I have a question and I really hope that I can explain this in English words.

At the moment I am reading Breant Ozwar's eBook SQL Server Setup Checklist and there is one thing that I am confused about.
I mean this one:

2.5.Provision storage for the OS and for SQL Server We don’t want to pile everything on the C drive, so create other volumes for SQL Server to spread across. Ideally, we’ll have separate logical drives for:
• SQL Server application folders – D:

• SQL Server databases data ﬁles – G:

• SQL Server database log ﬁles (including TempDB) – L:

• TempDB data ﬁle(s) – T:

• Backups – H:

I’ve learned /and it’s an advice from Microsoft two) to use separate drives for DB, Logs etc.
BUT I’m asking myself if this makes only sense when we have a physical server with e.g 5 drives, because every disk has different IOPS.

But when the Server got disks from a big storage (that’s managed by a Storage Controller) do we really need different disks for DB, Log etc.?
I mean the Storage Controller controls the IOPS. So if you have one drive and put DB, Log etc. just in different folders then they got the same IOPS when they are on different disks. Or is this wrong?

I hope you understand what I mean.
But the main question is: Does is make sense to put DB, Log, Temp on different drives when the Server get his drives from a Storage? Or does it make only sense when we have a physical server with physical disks?

Hopefully you can help me with this one, because I am not sure how to configure future Cluster systems (we don’t have much hardware servers).

Thanks in advance for reply and I hope your your doing all good.

Melissa

Comment: Probably going to get closed for opinion based but here goes.  I still prefer to create separate LUN's for each file type to more easily track performance / move specific items around internally if storage has multiple performance levels.  Also provides better containment for explosive file growth issues.

Comment: Maybe this blog from Brent Ozar about reliability and volume can help you : https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/06/separating-data-log-files-make-server-reliable/